# How to Host a WCF Service in WAS?

Tags: wcf, was

I have a simple WCF service with small logic like 
    Add(int x, int y) 
    Sub(int x,int y)
    Mul(int x,int y)
    Div(int x,int y)

Now I hosted the service using IIS and Self Hosting(using ServiceHost class)

Now I want to host the servcice with WAS.

How do I proceed..I don't have any idea about WAS..???

Comment: you just visit this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link..its helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You should refar this Links:

[How to: Host a WCF Service in a Managed Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

this is for how to host wcf service in WAS